# Can't install Strapi with PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql, strapi

I'm trying to install Strapi with PostgreSQL DB

```
yarn create strapi-app my-project
```

Every time, I get this error:

> Connection test failed: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5433

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer, I installed PostgreSQL and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Always best to provide versions of the packages and any relevant context so that it's more useful for future answer-seekers :)

Congrats on the solve!